# dpdk auto start after reboot

Tags: cron, dpdk

I try to do a cron job to let dpdk auto start after server reboot.

I create a bash script: it work well if run the bash script manually. But have problem when run in crontab.

```
#! /bin/bash
hugepages=1024
echo 1024 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge
sleep 5s
modprobe uio_pci_generic
modprobe vfio-pci
sleep 5s
/mypath/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --bind=uio_pci_generic 20:00.1
```

then in root user account, I create the cron tab:

```
@reboot sleep 30 && /var/diode/script/init.sh
```

After server reboot, I found the drive was mounted, but the uio_pci_generic was not added (i.e.: not run modprobe) 
Any idea, how to let it auto start after server reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See `dmesg` for the details why `modprobe` failed.
2. It depend on your operating system, but it is better to use `service(8)` or your OS startup scripts to run a DPDK app after restart. The `service(8)` allows to specify the right moment, when all the required subsystems have initialized.

Comment: I found need use /spin/modprobe